# 割り算を用いてfloat型を得ようとすると1.0になる

Tags: android

androidで[TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)を使っています。
画像の大きい辺/小さい辺　でズームの値を算出したいのですが、
コードで出力すると
width770
height1035
1.0
のようになり、1035/770が1.0になってしまいます。

```
contentImage.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    int width = contentImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = contentImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    System.out.println("width" + width);
    System.out.println("height" + height);
    int max = Math.max(width, height);
    int min = Math.min(width, height);
    float zoom = max / min;
    System.out.println(zoom);
    contentImage.setZoom(max / min);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

変数`max`と`min`が`int`型のため、`max / min`が整数どうしの割り算と(コンパイラで)解釈され、結果が整数(`int`)型になっているためと思います。

`max`と`min`を`float`型にすることで期待通りになると思います。